# Prevent crawling of mobile site will impact the actual's site ranking or indexing?

Tags: robots.txt, googlebot-mobile, mobile-first-index

We have a responsive mobile-first indexing site in place. Unfortunately, the m.example.com - mobile version is also there and it ranks for certain keywords.
We don't want to have such a separate m.example.com site.

Noted that, disallowing the mobile version site pages in robots.txt file would be the prompt solution to stop search engines to crawl or index those pages.
In such a case, will this impact our actual desktop or mobile-first indexing site's ranking or indexing?

Are there any other options to resolve this?

Ultimately, we don't want to have that m.example.com site be crawled or indexed or ranked.

Comment: Couldn't you just 301 the m.pages to the now responsive version of the page?